# Construct generic function

Tags: f#

I have a type:

```
type DictionaryCache<'a, 'b when 'a :comparison>()
```

And I have another type which contains some of this `DictionaryCache`:

```
type Cache() =

    let user = new DictionaryCache<int, User>()
    let userByLogin = new  DictionaryCache<string, User>()

    member this.User = user
    member this.UserByLogin = userByLogin
```

In the last type I want to create generic function which will return one of the members based on input parameter:

```
member this.CacheNameToDictionary (cacheName: string) : DictionaryCache<'a, 'b> option = 
    match cacheName with
    | "userByAutoincrementedId" -> Some(this.User)
    | "userByLogin" -> Some(this.UserByLogin)
    | _ -> None
```

But it doesn't work because of `type mismatch`.

Is there any way to rewrite this function ?

**Update:** here is a full code what I need to do:

```
type Cache() =

    let user = new DictionaryCache<int, User>()
    let userByLogin = new  DictionaryCache<string, User>()

    static let mutable instance = lazy(new Cache())
    static member Instance with get() = instance.Value

    member this.User = user
    member this.UserByLogin = userByLogin

    member this.Get (useCache: string) (cacheName: string) (id: 'a) longFunction exceptionFunction : 'b option =  

        let nameToDictionary() : DictionaryCache<'a, 'b> option = 
            match cacheName with
            | "userByAutoincrementedId" -> Some(this.User)
            | "userByLogin" -> Some(this.UserByLogin)
            | _ -> None

        let foo() : 'b option = 
            try
                longFunction()   
            with 
            | exn -> exceptionFunction exn
                     None

        match (useCache, nameToDictionary()) with
        | "true", Some(dictionary) -> 
            match dictionary.Get id with 
            | Some(result) -> Some(result)
            | _ -> match foo() with 
                   | Some(result) -> dictionary.Put id result
                                     Some(result)
                   | _ -> None
        | _ -> foo()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible - the problem is that the return type of the method would depend on the string that it gets as the input argument. The input string is only known at run-time, but the type needs to be known at compile-time.

You could use the `Choice` type which lets you return one of multiple different types:

```
member this.CacheNameToDictionary (cacheName: string) = 
    match cacheName with
    | "userByAutoincrementedId" -> Choice1Of3(this.User)
    | "userByLogin" -> Choice2Of3(this.UserByLogin)
    | _ -> Choice3Of3()
```

This works, but the return type lists all three alternatives and is pretty ugly:

```
Choice<DictionaryCache<int,User>, DictionaryCache<string,User>,unit>
```

Also, the consumer of this method will have to pattern match on the result and handle the two different dictionaries in different ways, so this might not make your code particularly beautiful.

Honestly, I think that you are adding a level of abstraction that you do not need. If there are two different keys, then you need different code to handle that and it's unlikely that you'll be able to write code that is extensible and adds third kind of dictionary.